# Jmeter - JSON Extractor - Large numbers erroring

Tags: json, jmeter, extractor

Hope someone can help me :)
I have the response json below :

```
"endValue":{"amount":12515920.97,"currencyCode":"EUR"}
```

and I'm using the JSON extractor to retrieve the "amount" number and is working fine for any numbers that have up till 6 characters before the decimal point, but for large numbers like this one, is actually saving "1.251592097E7" on my variable. Is this a limitation or is there any other way that I can have the full number extracted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "1.251592097E7" (1.251.. * 10^7) is just a different writing for your value (12515920.97) so is this really an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the digits of the number are there, it is just that it is being *displayed* in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

You can format the number when the program needs to display it, for example using [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Example{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double x = 12515920.97;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00");
        String result = df.format(x);
        System.out.println(result);
     }
}
```

Outputs:

> 12,515,920.97

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the value "as is" the easiest option is going for the [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and fetch your value using [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/)

Example code:

```
vars.put('your_variable_name_here', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).endValue.amount as String)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you for always giving solutions for the JSR223 element in groovy.